# Windows 10 'Disk read error' when installing

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, installation, ssd

I am trying to do a fresh install to a M.2 SSD, but I am encountering the error from the title.

I downloaded the Media creation tool from Microsoft and made a USB stick using it and a .iso file to use with Easy2Boot, but both bring to the same result.

My specs are:
i7-6700K
Asus Z170I Pro Gaming
SanDisk X110 SD6SP1M128G1002

The initial installation goes shoothly, but after the automatic restart the PC goes to the error 'Disk read error, press CTRL + ALT + DEL to restart'.

Afterwards the drive is normally seen in BIOS, but booting results to this error. It is also seen in drive management Windows 10(In my other HDD that I am trying to switch from).

I have tried fixing the drive with all the tools found in the installation USB(Start-up repair etc) and from command line using 'bootsect /nt60 C: /mdr' and setting the partition active using DiskPart.

What can I do? The drive is healthy by CrystalDisk and can be used as a data drive and I have had Ubuntu&Grub installed in it using it as the booting drive, but am unable to install Windows to it. The disk seems to be some OEM disk, not sure it that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have two disks in the system.
Windows may be installing the boot files on the old disk.
After installation, are you changing the BIOS settings to Boot to the new disk?
If so, then that is a problem if the boot files were installed onto the old drive.

If you try to boot from the old drive, you may now find 2 menu items, one for the old drive and one for the new drive.

If you are installing from USB, remove/unplug the old drive and just install to the new drive. Once it is booting OK, you can boot to either disk by changing the BIOS settings.

Comment: I do have two drives and my current Windows installation is on the other drive. The other drive should not be the problem, since I have always uninstalled it before I have tried to do the new install to the M.2 SSD.

I also tried installing the OS with the old drive installed(This led to the boot partition being in the old drive and giving me multiple selections on boot), but that did not help. The error is from the Windows's boot software, but still the installation is not working on the M.2 SSD.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB 3.0 drive enclosure, then try booting from that.
If you get a similar problem then the drive must be faulty.
If it works, then it maybe a SATA connectivity or driver issue?

Comment: I have one, but it doesn't support M.2 drives, so that is out of question. I have tried two different SSD checking programs and both report it as a 100% healthy drive. Could the drive still be bad or does that point into a mobo & SSD compability or settings issue?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise that your M.2 was an internal SSD card!
Did you set the boot order so it is the first boot device?
Some BIOSes do not support booting from internal SSD cards - did you check the mainboard manufacturers site for known issues and a BIOS update?

Comment: See http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/nvme_boot_guide_332098001us.pdf
You could try the UEFI BIOS settings suggested.
You can use  BCDBOOT xxx /ALL to install UEFI boot files

Comment: P.S. What is exact model of M.2 drive? Apparently there are different types and this can affect what BIOS settings you need to use...
I think the problem lies with your BIOS settings.

Comment: The model is in the question: SanDisk X110 SD6SP1M128G1002. Don't know what else to tell about it. I have also tried to look at the settigns, but have not found anything that would work.

Comment: Also I updated the BIOS to the newest just in case, even though I already were in the newer version. I''ll check that link tho when I have time

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the drive to boot.

First off my BIOS settings needed modifications. I had to use UEFI mode on everything, secure boot and disable CSM. This allowed me to make a actual UEFI installation from the USB to the SSD.

After this, the installation booted and went on to 'Getting things ready'. After the restart, no Windows installation was found and the PC booted straight to BIOS. I booted to the USB and opened a command prompt through the troubleshooting menu. I ran a combination of bootsect, bootrec, bcdboot, sfc /scannow and chkdsk. After them I rebooted and was greeted by the Windows 10 customization options.